# Possible to sort Visual Studio Community Intellisense suggestions by class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense, monodevelop

I'm a Unity developer and just made the jump from Monodevelop to Visual Studio Community. Overall Visual Studio Community is a huge improvement but there is one thing I miss that Monodevelop did better: With Monodevelop's auto-completion, it would always sort the functions / variables by class. With VSC, it just shows every possible conclusion in alphabetical order, including all class and base class methods and properties.

So, in the example shown here, if I start by typing "PauseManager." in Monodevelop, it will show autocomplete suggestions first for PauseManager, and then below that for it's base class System.Object.

[image: Monodevelop]

However when I type the same thing in Visual Studio, it will show me a huge list of methods and properties in alphabetical order, the majority of which I'm unlikely to be using.

[image: Visual Studio]

This is a very simple example of a small class with only one ancestor; you can imagine that this gets especially unwieldy when I've got a class with a dozen public methods and multiple ancestors, each of which have their own public methods and properties.

I've looked at the documentation for Intellisense here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense and I don't see any options for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Does anyone know of a way that this can be done? If not I may have to reluctantly go back to Monodevelop - looking through all these methods to sort out the ones relevant to what I'm doing it turning into an annoying little time waster.

Comment: I kind of see only the exactly same 5 suggestions in both of your screenshots ...? Just the ordering is different (usually the last used ones are on top and if there wasn't a last used one than alphabetical). You might have a look at ReSharper where you can customize this a lot but .. actually I would prefer to see all available options .. because you never know when you will need them

Comment: That's correct @derHugo - the suggestions are the same, but in Monodevelop, they are ordered with class first -> base class -> base class, etc. In Visual studio, they are ordered alphabetically, regardless of class. Which, when my class has 4 ancestors, each of which has a dozen or more public properties and methods, becomes very unwieldy to look at. I want to know if there is a way to make it work the way it does in Monodevelop. Intellisense looks like it's designed to be flexible so I'm hoping this is doable.

Comment: @SemperCallide, it seems you are using the VS Code not the VS community 2017, please try to download the free version: VS Community 2017 from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ and with the  Intellisense Filtering, we can be simpler to drill down to the results you're specially interested in like this: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmFAC75E5Ga-UBK0z

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT I am using VS Community 2017 v7.7.4 (build 1). Visual Studio Code does not play nice with Unity solutions, so it's not even really an option. How did you get those icons to appear beneath your code suggestions? Very interested to see if that could be a solution

Comment: @SemperCallide, please go to Tools-Options-Text Editor-C#-Intellisense and check the option "Show completion item filters" and save. The options is default checked and you can uncheck and check it to test or go Tools-Import and Export settings-Reset all settings and backup the current setting, choose 'General' setting to restore. If it still not works, please go to Help-About Microsoft Visual Studio and view the version and share it.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT There is no Options option under the Tools menu. However when I go into Preferences -> Text Editor -> IntelliSense, the only options are "Show completion list after a character is typed", "Complete with space or punctuation", "Show import items", and "Show EditorBrowsable.Advanced members". Are YOU sure you're using VS Community 2017? I don't think we're looking at the same program.

Comment: @SemperCallide, usually, we can go to Help-About Microsoft Visual Studio to check the version name or follow this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmx/2017/06/13/how-to-get-visual-studio-2017-version-number-and-edition/ to confirm it, if it is not the VS community 2017, please try to download it from my previous shared link to install, thanks.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT, I did go to version name, and mentioned the version I'm using: VS Community 2017 v7.7.4 (build 1). The website you are referring me to is the same one I downloaded it from. Would you mind sharing which version it is that you are using?

Comment: @SemperCallide, please check this: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv5QNuFrncKmFHLem-LNc_h2Qg7, btw, I guess your computer is Mac OSX and installed the VS for Mac version and mine is for Windows OS, that why you do not have this option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, apparently it is not possible currently.

There was an [issue/feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50755) but they closed it 5 months ago with kind of "won't do" as answer.
They linked it to a "duplicate" issue though I honestly don't really see that as a duplicate ...

Maybe you can search for plugins but built-in it seems not possible currently .. what is a pity because now that I know it exists somewhere I also miss it a bit :'D

Comment: That makes me a sad panda. Guess I'm stuck with Monodevelop for the time being. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score -3):

Go to

> Tools -> Get Tools and Features -> Modify

If you have multiple versions, select the proper version.

Scroll down and find Visual Studio Development Extension.

Click the checkbox and hit Modify.

That's all you need to do.

Enjoy✌️

Comment: "Get tools and features" is not an option underneath "Tools". The options are: "Assembly browser", "Regular expressions toolkit", "instruments", and "add custom tool..."

Comment: It's not clear how marking a checkbox on Development Extensions would have an impact on Intellisense at all.